# Chart library for backend

Tags: jquery, e-commerce

I'm looking for a little bit of advice about this:

I am developing an ecommerce component and I need to do some sales charts.

I have seen that some developers use the jqplot library and others use Google Chart.

Anyone have any experience on this or can advise me, please.

thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found this place to do some comparing http://www.fusioncharts.com/javascript-charting-comparison/

Comment: Also I am doing some research on use:    Hikashop -> google chart  //  Akeeba Suscription -> jqplot // jMarquet -> google chart // RedShop -> apparently has no charts // VirtueMart -> apparently has no charts

Comment: The [highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/) library is also easy to integrate.

Comment: Hi, Just want to inform you all that I finally used google chart. I decided for them because their documentation and solid company behind the technology. Thaks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

**Google Charts** is plain simple, and you don't add Kbytes to your download. I've implemented Google Charts to fill chart requirements.

**jqPlot library** (and similar libraries) provides a better feature set, and you can also customize advanced features, but you have to manage the full installation (version, size, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Rocket theme has been adding Chart.js to their templates lately, it looks pretty slick:

http://www.chartjs.org

I'm not a programmer though, so I don't know how it differs from the other options, but it sure looks nice.

Comment: I've looked into chart.js (I am a programmer) and indeed it has some nice features. The only issue with it is that the original developer hasn't been active for a while, so it might be a dead project.

Comment: @MathewLenning - I checked on Sep/2014 and there are many commits which came in last 60 days.

Comment: @miroxlav Awesome news.